# Using id to show item

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, wpdb

Im working on a project where i upload a gpx file and use the path of gpx to put in a shortcode plugin i use the post id the get a filled in shortcode
i use this code to get me the piece of info for the shortcode now i wanna make it so when i post a new post with the gpx file that it will automaticly gets the id and uses it im currently hard coded the id into it any1 has a fix for it?

```
<?php
global $wpdb; 
$thepost = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id = 5574" ) );
echo do_shortcode ('[sgpx gpx="'.'/wp-content/uploads/' . $thepost->meta_value . '"]'); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the GPX file is attached to the current page you can find it with [`get_attached_media()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_media/), e.g.

```
$gpx_files = get_attached_media( 'application/gpx+xml' );
if ( count( $gpx_files ) >= 1 ) {
    echo do_shortcode ('[sgpx gpx="' . wp_get_attachment_url( $gpx_files[0]->ID ) . '"]');
} else {
    echo '<p class="warning">No GPX file attached!</p>';
}
```